# jQuery limit selector to it's parent

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-selectors

i'm trying to create a context menu for jQuery, i was using the jQuery UI dialog and modifying 
it to fit my needs:

```
var menu = $(this);
menu.dialog('option', 'position', [jsEvent.clientX, jsEvent.clientY]);
    menu.unbind('dialogopen');
    menu.bind('dialogopen', function(event, ui) {

        $('.ui-dialog-titlebar').hide();
        $('.ui-widget-overlay').unbind('click');
        $('.ui-widget-overlay').css('opacity', 0);
        $('.ui-widget-overlay').click(function() {
            menu.dialog('close');
        });
    });
    menu.dialog('open');
```

now, this only works if there is no UI that uses `.ui-dialog-titlebar` since they will disappear when ever context menu fires

i thought of doing this:

```
var id = '#'+$(this).attr('id');
```

and select elements only in my menu

```
$(id+' .ui-dialog-titlebar').hide();
```

but it doesn't seems to work, the `.ui-dialog-titlebar` is still there

how do i select elements in the menu **ONLY**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To find all elements with a certain class within another element you can use `find()` :

```
$(this).find('.ui-dialog-titlebart').hide();
```

If you'd like to hide all elements with a certain class except `UL` elements :

```
$('.ui-dialog-titlebar').not('ul').hide();
```

or target just `LI` elements

```
$('li.ui-dialog-titlebar').hide();
```

Comment: I used $(this).find('.ui-dialog-titlebart').hide(); and it doesn't work, it looks like the dialog is opened before the binded events fire, is there a way to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.ui-dialog-titlebart', this).hide()
```

$('the item you want', this) is shortcut for selecting the item only if it is a child of the current element

Comment: is there a difference between $('.ui-dialog-titlebart', this) and $(this).find('.ui-dialog-titlebart') ? performance wise....

Answer (score 1):

You can try like this,

```
var menu = $(this);
$(menu).find('.ui-dialog-titlebar').hide();
```

You can refer [jQuery Selector](http://jquery-this.blogspot.com/2013/06/jquery.html). If needed..